# What's the preferred way of throwing exceptions in Magento?

Tags: error, best-practice, exception

All of the following methods are used in Magento core so which one is the preferred (or the latest "best practice") way?

- `Mage::throwException('Some Message')` - **732 Usages**
- `throw new Exception('Some Message')` - **419 Usages**
- `throw Mage::exception('Vendor_Module', 'Some Message')` - **94 Usages**
  <sub>(need to create a `Vendor_Module_Exception` class)</sub>

Comment: how did you find the execption count?I am asking it for curiosity to know it !!!

Comment: @RajeevKTomy I'm guessing a grep from the command line - something like `grep -r throwException /path/to/magento/app/code/core | wc -l ; grep -r throw\ new /path/to/magento/app/code/core | wc -l ; grep -r throw\ Mage /path/to/magento/app/code/core | wc -l` - though that requires that you know what too look for.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The call `Mage::throwException` is used to throw exceptions of the specific `Mage_Core_Exception` variety. These are generally used to present error messages to the end user. For examples of this, do a quick search for `Mage::throwException` in the Mage_Checkout module, you'll find many instances where the error message is actually being translated before it's thrown, as it's ultimately going to be added to the session object and displayed to the user on the resulting page.

Using `new Exception` or something like `new My_Custom_Exception` would normally be where you are throwing errors internal to the application, errors which most likely should never be displayed to the end user. Maybe you catch these and handle them gracefully (good use for a custom exception type in some cases), or other times they end out caught, logged and terminate the request with a more generic error message being displayed to the user.

I've never personally used `Mage::exception` but it appears to be an attempt to pattern having a unique exception type for each module. There would be no harm done in using it, as it is essentially a factory which returns an exception instance for the given module, although (at the time of this writing) it does not implement any support for such things as overrides.

Comment: I like your reasoning here - it's in plain English :)

Comment: I called `Mage::throwException('my error message')` in my helper class but nothing happens??

Answer (score 16):

You've done the hard part, finding out how often they're used :)

**tl;dr:** IMHO, you should use `Mage::throwException` most often, falling back to `Mage::exception` when you need to raise an exception type from outside of the scope of your module, if for no other reason than the session messaging ability and the fact that you don't have to type `throw new` in front of it.

Here's the breakdown:

- `Mage::throwException` is essentially a wrapper for `Mage_Core_Exception($message)` with the additional functionality of being able to add the exception to a session via a `getSingleton` call chained with `addMessage`
- `new Exception()` is the core PHP way to throw an exception, but requires you to use the `throw` keyword and is probably the slightest big more "performant" as the other two are wrappers with extra functionality.
- As mentioned, `Mage::exception` is a wrapper as well, but has the benefit of allowing you to instantiate your own exception class. This is *really helpful* if you're a plugin developer and need to make custom logs for exceptions, separately, without the functionality that `logException` provides (e.g., no stack trac) or want to make an API call on exception, etc. It's also handy when you want to `throw` an exception of a differing class type, for instance, what happens in `Mage_Paypal`, frequently raising a `Mage_Core` exception type.

Comment: Talk about timing… less than 10 seconds apart. :)

Comment: The reasoning of preference between `new Exception()` and `Mage::exception()` is not clear to me at best. When I look into `Mage::exception()` code, I don't see *any* benefit over `throw $exception`, it actually hinders you to choose the exception class you've configured standard auto-loading for in (your/an) extension as it prefixes the classname, hinders static analysis and does not allow you to call additional methods on the exception at it throws directly.