# Difference between "Mage_Core_Exception $e" and "Exception $e"

Tags: magento-1.9, best-practice, exception

I found different cases to use Magento throw exception, I want to know what is the difference between  `(Mage_Core_Exception $e)` and `(Exception $e)` ? I found [What's the preferred way of throwing exceptions in Magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6674/whats-the-preferred-way-of-throwing-exceptions-in-magento/6675#6675) answer, but it's not precise for me. Is `Mage::throwException` is the correct one and that we should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just PHP type hinting ... the one expects  `$e` to be element of class  `Exception`, the other one expects `Mage_Core_Exception`.

Since `class Mage_Core_Exception extends Exception` the only "differences" are [three changed methods](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Exception.php#L40-L76).

For `Mage::throwException()` see `app/Mage.php`. At the end it is throws a new exception of class `Mage_Core_Exception` *(thats child of PHPs `Exception`)*.

```
public static function throwException($message, $messageStorage = null)
{
    if ($messageStorage && ($storage = self::getSingleton($messageStorage))) {
        $storage->addError($message);
    }
    throw new Mage_Core_Exception($message);
}
```

Comment: The `three changed methods` link doesn't work, however your answer does not answer my question, I want to know exactly the difference between, according to you answer you mean that `(Exception $e)` and `(Mage_Core_Exception $e)` is the same thing and there no difference ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only the behavior of the (now correctly linked) mehtods changed. So go for `Mage_Core_Exception` and `Mage::throwException()` :)

Comment: I'll downvote your answer because you you gave me a link that not working :)

Comment: @Prince it's okay if you'd accept at least :P

Comment: I accept on condition if you give a few points :)

Comment: @Prince you get 2 REP for accepting an answer. This has to be enough :P

Comment: Nop i need 100, you have many ^^

Comment: Na, thats not many @Prince :) Serious again ... i want to see the questions where I participate closed, so do you havev any question about this exeptions?

Comment: i want to see the questions where I participate closed lol why ? And if it remains open it's not a problem, it also allows to have other answers, and maybe better

Comment: @Prince if I spent my time to answer questions it's not for REP (cant buy something from this) just want help and learn bit ... so as questioneer, why not upvote useful and accept if it answers the question? Just to mark it answered. :) Btw ... no problem if there is better answer, you can also change the accepted one :)

Comment: I accepted your answer and you want to have also an upvote again ? Wow you are so gourmand sven ? And you tell me it's not for reputations it's for help :P !! And in general when users see that an answer is accepted they no longer respond again.

Comment: This was general meaning ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63506/discussion-between-prince-and-sv3n).